# Gutter ads condition based if gutter on site 1024px and else remove gutter site for original view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i hide Gutter ads based on condition if the display size is more than 1024px on desktop otherwise the gutter ads will be shown.

I just want to remove div with gutter ads code on mobile devices for different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to achieve the results you want.
for example to hide add on viewport is 480 pixels or less.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.gutter-add-div{
    display: none;
 }
}
```